# Hadoop scheduler preserving data locality

Tags: hadoop, scheduler

I checked couple of documents but I have doubts regarding task scheduling in Hadoop preserving Data locality.
Assuming input data for task `t` is `D1` and the replication factor is 3 (which means I have 3 copies of D1 stored on 3 different servers) now when `t` arrives, On which severer `t` will be assigned? (considering default scheduler).

Answer (score 1):

Hadoop will try to use all available mapper slots. If it has a way to assign task preserving data locality then it will do that (that is, if one of those 3 servers which contain a copy of D1 has available mapper slot it will try to put it on that server). If all mappers on those 3 servers are occupied, but there is another server with available mapper slots then task will be placed on that mapper.